# Modeling User Roles Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, database-design

Just a design question.

I have a entity essentially a user type who is a `Therapist`. The therapist is able to log on to the system as a user and perform the required functionality. There are however other users too, e.g `Admin`.

I am wondering the best way to model this.

- Should `Therapist` extend the `User` class and in the subclass add the user specific additional properties? Or
- Is this more of a role scenario?

A colleague suggested that no class should ever really extend `User` as if they adopt a different role then that subclass will become diluted and redundant. It is more of a role.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds more like a role to me. What if a therapist is also an admin? You won't be able to model this with inheritance.

Comment: yes i was thinking that too. But a therapist will have much of the same propoerties as a user e.g. username, password, address, email etc except an additional specific property called therapistSummary which summaries who they are and what they do. So should not the therapist re-use the User object in this case? Sorry for my daft questioning.

Comment: Oh and also, all associations are specific to the therapist, e.g. TherapyProvision, TreatableSymptom etc. So this means all these classes would be associated with the User Object which doesnt sound right, as they are specific to the Therapist??

Comment: You could have a Therapist entity with a OneToOne association with User. If this association exists, it means that the user has the therapist role. And all your TherapistXxx entities can have an association with the Therapist entity.

Comment: i see, that makes sense JB Nizet. But either way the User class would then need to have a reference to the Therapist class? I cant see a way of making this somewhat generic so the Therapist isnt visible in the User class although using a one to one would prevent all therapist specific entities hanging off the User class directly. thanks for y

Comment: I'd rather add a non-nullable unique foreign key in the therapist table, referencing the user ID. Whether you make the association unidirectional or bidirectional is up to you. A therapist must know about its user (to be able to get the name of the therapist, for example), but a user must not necessarily know about its potential therapist. You would then have to use a query to know if a user is a therapist.